# How to use Diffie-Hellman key in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, steganography

I am doing a video steganography project. I have problem how to use a key using Diffie-Hellman key for encryption part from sender and receiver site. Here is the code of Diffie-Hellman key. I get key to use for encryption, but my problem is how to use this key for encrypt.

```
%%Diffie-Hellman key exchange    
prime_number=23;
base_value=5;

% now alice chose key and sent to bob ...let us take example     
a=6;

% Alice=mod(base_value^a,prime_number);    
Alice=mod(5^6,23);

%now bob select secret key....let us take example  
b=19;    
Bob=mod(5^19,23);

%Exchange key alice and bob    
Alice_secretkey = mod(19^6,23);

%Alice_secretkey is 2 after calculation i get    
Bob_secreykey = mod(8^19,23);

%Bob_secreykey is 4 after calculation i get
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask. Is there something wrong with the code you've shown us? Or do you not know how to use a key for encryption? What have you read so far?

Comment: yes sir i do not know how to use key for encyrption